# how to start new proactive conversation dialog without ending to current ongoing dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

- SDK Language: `Node.js`
- SDK Version: 3.6
- Development Environment:

  - Node.js: 6.9.5
  - npm version: 4.5.0

#### Issue Description

Let's say the user is currently doing conversation with bot, In between, we want to send some survey to the user through proactive message (bot to the user). After feeling survey user should get back the old conversation state, from which point he started the survey.

Or in simple words how to start new proactive conversation dialog without ending to current ongoing dialog

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible. I would recommend you to review the [core-proactiveMessages Node.js samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages). In particular, the [startNewDialog sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog) shows exactly the scenario you are looking at.

Per the sample documentation:

> **startNewDialog**: In this case, we want more than just send an ad hoc
>   message: We want to interrupt the current conversation, initiate a new
>   one and have the original conversation wait until the new one is
>   finished.